# how to avoid redrawing the image when calling paint in java applets?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I am trying to set an image as a background for the applet. whenever the paint method is called, it redraws the image again; and this causes flickering. how can I make the image be drawn only once?

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main extends Applet  {

    Image background;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(800, 600);

        try {
            System.out.println(getCodeBase());
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("1.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading the image");
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);


    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: Switching to JApplet will actually likely fix this, since I believe it does double buffering for you which should stop the flickering.

Comment: 3) Don't attempt to set the size of applets in Java code!  The size of an applet is set by the HTML that loads it. 4) remember to call `super.paint(g)` as the first line when overriding functionality. 5) An applet would not be able to access a `File` on the server, and only a trusted applet can load a resource from the user's machine..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JApplet instead of the old Applet. JApplet should already have double buffering, which decreases flickering.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all top level containers aren't double buffered, but perhaps you could put an example together that proves me wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing this is because most top level containers are not double buffered (in fact if I recall correctly, AWT components aren't double buffered at all).

This means if you override `paint` on any top level container, you will see this problem.

A better solution would be to create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel`, override its `paintComponent` method and paint the image there.

You should also make sure that you are calling `super.paintXxx` to ensure that the `Graphics` context is prepared correctly for painting.

You can the add this component to something like `JApplet` or `JFrame` as you need